# jQuery onblur not working

Tags: jquery, onblur

```
$('#lPass').focus(function() {  
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';
        $(this).after('<input type="password" id="lPass" size="10" value="'+this.value+'"/>').remove();
}).blur(function() {
    alert(1);
});

<input id="lPass" type="text" size="10" value="Password"/>
```

*onblur* not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of focus and blur

> .live() has been deprecated. 
>   Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead.

because you are adding the input in run time, so it adds to the page with out the events, live:

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now or in the future.

**Example:**

```
$('#lPass').on('focus', function() {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';
    $(this).after('<input type="password" id="lPass" size="10" value="' + this.value + '"/>').remove();
});


$('#lPass').on('blur', function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: .live tells jQuery that you want this to happen to something whether it was in the original file or was made by javascript. That first part in quotes before the function tells it what kind of event you're looking for (focus in the first instance, blur in the second). Then you define what you want to happen.

Comment: .live is removed as of jQuery 1.9+, use .on instead

Answer (score 2):

This for your exact code:

```
$('#lPass').live('focus', function() {  
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';
    $(this).after('<input type="password" id="lPass" size="10" value="'+this.value+'"/>').remove();
}).live('blur', function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first issue I see is that your selector is an ID of #lPass, yet, within that selector you attempt to insert a new tag with that same ID.  ID must be unique on the page.  THEN you attempt to remove with the .remove() - seems to make no sense to me.

Just use the .remove() or use a new id...

OR clarify what you want to do.

As for the .blur, just use a blur, but the ID must be fixed, or use the .live() as others suggest if you wish to blur the NEW field you added.